# Depend on workspace package from a branch in a package.json?

Tags: git, npm, dependencies, branch, monorepo

Let's say in my package.json I depend on a `next` branch by declaring in my dependencies:

```
react-admin": "marmelab/react-admin#next"
```

That repository has workspaces (local packages so to say). For example: [`ra-ui-materialui`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui)

What do I add to `dependencies` of my `package.json` to depend on `ra-ui-materialui` in the same `next` branch?